# The transitions are bugged in Safari

Tags: html, safari, css-transitions, css

i found a strange bug.
I need to make a transition width/height on a box, i need this box to be absolute and inline-block.
This works fine with all browsers except safari.

Here is an exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/575FE/

HTML:

```
<div id="block">
SOME TEXT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#block {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s all;
    -o-transition: 0.6s all;
    transition: 0.6s all;
    display: inline-block;
}

#block:hover {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Combination of inline-block + absolute make the transition not working in safari.
Anyone know how to fix it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Firefox has a similar bug. You can't change the position property if you want transition.

Comment: What does 'buggy' mean? You need to be more specific.

Comment: There is no transition. The changes happen immediately

Comment: Add the position property to the unhovered state. Then it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/575FE/6/

Comment: @3rror404 This work fine for me with IE11, FF30, chrome35.

Comment: @Paulie_D No transition effect with safari.

Comment: @Keveun You're right. They must have fixed it recently

Comment: @Paulie_D The problem is, i only want absolute property in hover. :/

Comment: Not sure that even make sense,,,,why would you need it **just on hover**.

Comment: Some context would be useful here

Comment: @Paulie_D It's an gallery pictures, imagine a container like 200x200px, and 4 pictures in container (2x2) like 100x100px each, i need those images inline-block, when you click on image this image up to 200x200px and appears on top of other (absolute/transition).

Comment: Well, you can't transition to `position:absolute` anyway...it's not an animatable property. You might have to re-think.

Comment: you can use float property instead of inline-block and relative instead absolute

Comment: @Kiran, oh, float: left; instead of inline-block works fine with position: absolute; Thanks.


Basicaly, i wanted this: http://jsfiddle.net/575FE/16/
But i used scale() here, and scale make a poor (realy bad) quality on picture with safari and video with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **position:absolute** from `#block:hover`

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/575FE/8/)**

```
#block:hover {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: "i need this box to be absolute and inline-block" - OP